# How to get a data from html element from ajax responseText without jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'd like to get data from ajax response, but this code not working:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://localhost/test/test.php", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        alert(request.responseText.document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML);
    }   
}
```

The console shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined.
```

Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `DOMParser` to convert `html` string to document fragment

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://localhost/test/test.php", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(request.responseText, "text/html");
    var elem = doc.getElementById("div1");
    alert(elem.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

alternatively, you can set the `responseType` to `document`

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "file.html", true);
request.responseType = "document";
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    var doc = request.response;
    var elem = doc.getElementById("div1");
    alert(elem.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/lkpveDD31fYY1gmflK9W?p=preview

Comment: It's amazing that you understood what he wanted +1

Comment: @guest271314

Can you tell me, which option will be faster ?

Comment: @Star089 You can profile each approach at `devtools`

Answer (score -1):

Request object isn't a DOM element nor does it have the methods that the native DOM has.

Fix your code with:

```
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", "http://localhost/test/test.php", true);
            request.send(null);
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {

              if (request.readyState == 4) {
                  alert(request.responseText);
              }


            }
```

Comment: So, how can I get html code from div from ajax request?

Comment: Do you want to display the response text in the HTML document?

Comment: No, I want to take data from all td tags from table with ID table1

Comment: We need to see your `responseText` otherwise we can't give you the proper selector.

Comment: @Star089 _"No, I want to take data from all td tags from table with ID table1"_ `id` in `html` `document` should be unique

Comment: thnks for willingness to help, code from guest271314 is sufficient :)

Comment: Not really sure why there is a downvote - the original question asked: `Any ideas what's causing this?`